# Get text between 2 tags that change (regex)(php)

Tags: php, html, regex

How should I get the text between 2 html tags that are not always the same. How should I let regex "ignore" a part.

Lets say this is my html:

```
<html>
...
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDomain_ctl03_lblName">stirng 1</span>
...
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDomain_ctl04_lblName">string 2</span>
...
<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDomain_ctl53_lblName">string 3</span>
...
</html>
```

As you see the ctlxx part is not always the same, this code only gets the first string:

```
preg_match('#\\<span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDomain_ctl03_lblName">(.+)\\</span>#s',$html,$matches);
$match = $matches[0];
echo $match;
```

How can I let regex ignore the ctlxx part and echo all the strings?

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to echo values of span tags?

Comment: Nope the strings between the span tags, so in this case: string 1, string 2, string 3

Comment: You can use javascript . getElementById("id").innerHTML will give you the content

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by DomDocument and DomXpath with using preg_match

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$x = new DOMXpath($dom);

// Next two string to use Php functions within within Xpath expression  
$x->registerNamespace("php", "http://php.net/xpath");
$x->registerPHPFunctions();

// Select span tags with proper id
foreach($x->query('//span[php:functionString("preg_match", "/ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvDomain_ctl\d+_lblName/", .)]') as $node) 
    echo $node->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to solve it using regular expression then you can do something like this

```
<?php
    preg_match('/<span id="[^"]*">(.+)<\/span>/is',$html,$matches);
    $match = $matches[0];
    echo $match;
```